# How to access a specific list within a list?

Tags: c#, list, sublist

I have a `List<List<string>>` information; that is full of 3 other lists. I need to be able to do three separate things on each of these sublists. How do i access each sublist?

For more clarity the lists were added to the main list like this

```
infomration.Add(sublist1);//where each sublist is a List<string> and information is a <List<List<string>>
infomration.Add(sublist2);
infomration.Add(sublist3);
reutrn information;
```

Comment: show us how the list looks like in code...

Comment: @codingbiz, just edited the code- Now its visible

Comment: It's not clear enough - how are the list assigned or related to the main list. To avoid guessing and trying to read the OP's mind

Comment: Assuming List<List<string>> someList = .....; someList[0] will get you the first list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wish to perform 3 separate operations on the 3 elements (lists) in your list.  Since `Lists` are indexed, why not just access them this way?

```
PerformOperationOne(myListofLists[0]);
PerformOperationTwo(myListofLists[1]);
PerformOperationThree(myListofLists[2]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Enumerable.ElementAt` (or the simple indexer of the list):

```
List<string> first = lists.ElementAt(0);
List<string> second = lists.ElementAt(1);
List<string> third = lists.ElementAt(2);

doSomethingWith(first);
doSomethingWith(second);
doSomethingWith(third);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<List<string>> lists = new List<List<string>>();
    lists.ForEach(i =>
    {
        i.Count();//do something
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be using a `Dictionary<string,List<string>>` if you need to access each list separately, though since you need to do something different with each list, perhaps three separate lists would be best, instead of putting them all into a single combined structure.

This will allow you to access each list by a key.

```
var aList = myDictionary["the wanted list key"];
```

Though, if you know the index of the internal lists, you can access them by index:

```
var anInnerList = listOfLists[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

To do the same operation on all lists in the collection

```
foreach(List<string> list in information) {
    DoSomething(list);
}
```

However if you need to do something different on each item, you could specify an index as per a previous solution - or, for extra functionality you could put it in a switch to perform multiple different actions on each entity.

```
int counter = 0;
foreach(List<string> list in information) {
    switch(counter) {
        case 0:
            // First action
            list = DoSomething(list);
            break;
        case 1:
            // Second action
            list = DoSomethingElse(list);
            break;
        case 2:
            // Third action
            list = DoSomethingWeird(list);
            list = DoAnotherThing(list);
            break;
        default:
            // Do something if there's more than 3 items in the list
            SendErrorReport();
            break;
    }
    counter++;
}
```